# Laravel Permissions and Roles with Gate/Can

Tags: laravel

at the moment i do a tutorial called "roles and permissions in laravel" from codecourse.com.

In part 4 of the tutorial i have the problem i get everytime the result true.
If i ask for the permission "edit posts" it should show me true, if i ask for the permission "delete posts" it should show me false.

I checked the database relationship, but there is no relationship between the user and the permission "delete posts".

Only if i ask for a permission that not exist like "blabla" (i mean not exist in the database) i got false.

I believe he is only checking is there a permission with this name and not checking have the user the permission.

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function (\illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
$user = $request->user();

dump($user->can("delete posts"));});
```

HasPermissionTrait.php

```
trait HasPermissionsTrait {

public function hasRole(...$roles)
{
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if ($this->roles->contains('name', $role)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

public function hasPermissionTo($permission) {
    //Check has permission through role

    return $this->hasPermission($permission);
}

protected function hasPermission($permission) {
    return (bool) $this->permissions->where('name', $permission->name);
}

public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'users_roles');

}

public function permissions() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'users_permissions');

}
```

PermissionsServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Permission::get()->map(function ($permission) {
        Gate::define($permission->name, function ($user) use ($permission) {
            return $user->hasPermissionTo($permission);
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Register the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}
```

you can watch my full code here -> https://github.com/RahmanG/joko

On this image you can see the Auth. There is no permission "delete posts". But you can see the Gate is giving true.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ne8wo.jpg

Thank you for supporting

Comment: Is it necessary to register that PermissionServiceProvder??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got already the answer. Thank you to tykus from laracasts.com

tykus:

Looks like your trait might have a mistake:

```
protected function hasPermission($permission) {
    return (boolean) $this->permissions->where('name', $permission->name);
}
```

$this->permissions->where('name', $permission->name) returns a Builder instance, and an object cast to a boolean always is true.

You probably need to return a count or first - something that would be falsey if there was no permission, e.g.

```
protected function hasPermission($permission) {
    return (boolean) $this->permissions->where('name', $permission->name)->count();
}
```